# Convert array of objects to an array of float

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have an array of arrays as follows:

```
segments[:30]
array([array([ 131.2]), array([ 124.1]), 0.23679025210440158,
       array([ 133.65]), array([ 123.3]), 0.3221912760287523,
       array([ 116.7]), array([ 147.7]), 0.24318619072437286,
       array([ 102.3]), array([ 120.55]), 0.07436020392924547,
       array([ 130.25]), array([ 100.5625]), 0.029634355247253552,
       array([ 143.6]), array([ 132.4]), 0.5843092009425164,
       array([ 151.65]), array([ 131.6]), 0.4865431547164917,
       array([ 143.3]), array([ 152.05]), 0.2774583905003965,
       array([ 111.65]), array([ 125.]), 0.23880321211181582,
       array([ 123.1875]), array([ 79.5625]), 0.1562070251966361], dtype=object)
```

I would like to get rid of `array([ 131.2])` and extract only the value `131.2`.

My expected output is:

```
array([131.2, 124.1, 0.23679025210440158,
           133.65, 123.3, 0.3221912760287523,
           116.7,147.7, 0.24318619072437286,
           102.3, 120.55, 0.07436020392924547,....])
```

I have tried the following:

```
np.array(segments)
```

but it doesn't make any change to my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Method 1: list comprehension

One way would be to iterate through and extract the floats when your values are `np.arrays` with a list comprehension:

```
np.array([i[0] if isinstance(i, np.ndarray) else i for i in segments])
```

Which returns:

```
array([1.31200000e+02, 1.24100000e+02, 2.36790252e-01, 1.33650000e+02,
       1.23300000e+02, 3.22191276e-01, 1.16700000e+02, 1.47700000e+02,
       2.43186191e-01, 1.02300000e+02, 1.20550000e+02, 7.43602039e-02,
       1.30250000e+02, 1.00562500e+02, 2.96343552e-02, 1.43600000e+02,
       1.32400000e+02, 5.84309201e-01, 1.51650000e+02, 1.31600000e+02,
       4.86543155e-01, 1.43300000e+02, 1.52050000e+02, 2.77458391e-01,
       1.11650000e+02, 1.25000000e+02, 2.38803212e-01, 1.23187500e+02,
       7.95625000e+01, 1.56207025e-01])
```

This is a naive but straightforward way to do thing. But this could be very slow on a very large array.

## Method 2: Reshaping

If your structure is always the same as your example, *i.e.* 2 arrays followed by a float, then you can reshape your array, extract the floats from 2 out of every 3 values, and then concatenate the data back together in the same order:

```
x = segments.reshape(-1,3)

f = np.concatenate(x[:,[0,1]].flatten()).reshape(-1,2)

l = x[:,2].reshape(-1,1)

np.concatenate((f,l),1).flatten()
```

Which returns:

```
array([131.2, 124.1, 0.23679025210440158, 133.65, 123.3,
       0.3221912760287523, 116.7, 147.7, 0.24318619072437286, 102.3,
       120.55, 0.07436020392924547, 130.25, 100.5625,
       0.029634355247253552, 143.6, 132.4, 0.5843092009425164, 151.65,
       131.6, 0.4865431547164917, 143.3, 152.05, 0.2774583905003965,
       111.65, 125.0, 0.23880321211181582, 123.1875, 79.5625,
       0.1562070251966361], dtype=object)
```

**Explanation**

Just to aid visualizing what was happening here, you can look at the reshaped data I extracted before concatenating back together.

```
>>> x
array([[array([131.2]), array([124.1]), 0.23679025210440158],
       [array([133.65]), array([123.3]), 0.3221912760287523],
       [array([116.7]), array([147.7]), 0.24318619072437286],
       [array([102.3]), array([120.55]), 0.07436020392924547],
       [array([130.25]), array([100.5625]), 0.029634355247253552],
       [array([143.6]), array([132.4]), 0.5843092009425164],
       [array([151.65]), array([131.6]), 0.4865431547164917],
       [array([143.3]), array([152.05]), 0.2774583905003965],
       [array([111.65]), array([125.]), 0.23880321211181582],
       [array([123.1875]), array([79.5625]), 0.1562070251966361]],
      dtype=object)

>>> f
array([[131.2   , 124.1   ],
       [133.65  , 123.3   ],
       [116.7   , 147.7   ],
       [102.3   , 120.55  ],
       [130.25  , 100.5625],
       [143.6   , 132.4   ],
       [151.65  , 131.6   ],
       [143.3   , 152.05  ],
       [111.65  , 125.    ],
       [123.1875,  79.5625]])
>>> l
array([[0.23679025210440158],
       [0.3221912760287523],
       [0.24318619072437286],
       [0.07436020392924547],
       [0.029634355247253552],
       [0.5843092009425164],
       [0.4865431547164917],
       [0.2774583905003965],
       [0.23880321211181582],
       [0.1562070251966361]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Your first list comprehension is faster - at least for this sample.

Comment: That's quite likely, but I'm assuming for very large arrays, this would not be the case. Can't believe I overlooked `hstack`! For some reason I was under the impression it wouldn't work. +1 for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

`concatenate` makes all elements arrays, but has problems with dimensions.  Some are 1d, some 0d:

```
In [109]: np.concatenate(arr)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-062a20dcc2f7> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate(arr)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

`hstack` works because it first converts everything to 1d arrays with `[atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup]`:

```
In [110]: np.hstack(arr)
Out[110]: 
array([1.31200000e+02, 1.24100000e+02, 2.36790252e-01, 1.33650000e+02,
       1.23300000e+02, 3.22191276e-01, 1.16700000e+02, 1.47700000e+02,
       2.43186191e-01, 1.02300000e+02, 1.20550000e+02, 7.43602039e-02,
       1.30250000e+02, 1.00562500e+02, 2.96343552e-02, 1.43600000e+02,
       1.32400000e+02, 5.84309201e-01, 1.51650000e+02, 1.31600000e+02,
       4.86543155e-01, 1.43300000e+02, 1.52050000e+02, 2.77458391e-01,
       1.11650000e+02, 1.25000000e+02, 2.38803212e-01, 1.23187500e+02,
       7.95625000e+01, 1.56207025e-01])
```

The result is numeric dtype (not object).

Processing an object array requires some sort of python level iteration - except for limited operations like reshape which don't actually manipulate the elements.  And iteration on an object is slower than iteration on a list (but faster than Python level iteration on a numeric array).

---

```
In [113]: [np.atleast_1d(i) for i in arr]   # consistent dimensions
Out[113]: 
[array([131.2]),
 array([124.1]),
 array([0.23679025]),
 array([133.65]),
 array([123.3]),
 ...]

In [116]: [np.asarray(i) for i in arr]  # mixed dimensions
Out[116]: 
[array([131.2]),
 array([124.1]),
 array(0.23679025),
 array([133.65]),
 array([123.3]),...]
```

---

Internally `atleast_1d` does some testing on the dimensions.  It also works with `*args` so we can write

```
In [123]: np.atleast_1d(*arr)
Out[123]: 
[array([131.2]),
 array([124.1]),
 array([0.23679025]),
 array([133.65]),
 array([123.3]),
 ...]
```

and hence

```
np.concatenate(np.atleast_1d(*arr))
```

Timing test show that `@sacul's` 'naive' list comprehension is fastest: `np.array([i[0] if isinstance(i, np.ndarray) else i for i in segments])`